# Notify list in a fragment when sql lite database has new entries added

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have an android activity which has a tabbed navigation structure . I show a list on the first tab with option to add items to their favorite which is shown in second tab. The favorite entries are maintained in sqlite db.

Can someone suggest the right way to structure the code so that if an item is marked favorite in First Fragment and entry is saved in database . How to get the second fragment reflect the changes.

P.S:The second fragment does a select all from favorties table and has a list.

Comment: fire select query in database from second fragment.

Comment: use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus . This https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md will give idea on how to use

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `OnPageChangeListener` on your adapter, determine when the second page is displayed, get the data from the database and if it is different replace in the list.